# Why do I get an exception when using .CER Certificate with httpClient in my console app?

Tags: c#, certificate, httpclient

I've been looking around the web and tested different solutions, but I still have not found a solution that can solve my problem. 
I keep getting an exception, after adding my certificate with .CER extension. When attempting to invoke the web service from my console app, it fails with the message saying:

> Could not establish a secure channel for ssl/tls.

Is it something I'm doing wrong in my code? Hope that I can get some help...

```
public void GetCVR()
{
    string url = @"My url";
    string certPath = @"My Path to the Certificate.cer";

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
        (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
        {
            switch (sslPolicyErrors)
            {
                case System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors:
                case System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch:
                case System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable:
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sslPolicyErrors + " " + chain + " " + certificate);
            Console.ReadLine();

            return true;
        };

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(certPath));
        handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;

        var _client = new HttpClient(handler);
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response =  _client.GetAsync(url).Result;
    }
}
```

**Update 15-09-2019**
Ok I change my code above and I add two methods:

```
  private void AddCertificate(string cer)
  {
      X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
      store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
      store.Add(new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(cer)));
      store.Close();
  }

  private X509Certificate2 GetMyCert()
  {
      string certThumbprint = "7a61a6fc";
      X509Certificate2 cert = null;

      // Load the certificate
      var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
      store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

      X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates.Find
      (
         X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber,
         certThumbprint,
         false    
      );

      if (certCollection.Count > 0)
      {
         cert = certCollection[0];
      }
      store.Close();
      return cert;
  }
```

So instead of:

```
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(certPath));
```

I first add the certificate to the key store and then I retrieve it as follows.
In debug it looks fine.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = GetMyCert();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
```

But it still fails with the message saying:

> Could not establish a secure channel for ssl/tls.

Comment: For client certificate authentication, you must have the private key. Best way is to use certificates from the key store (not manually loaded from file)

Comment: It is only the cer file I got from the sevice provider and they wrote me that it is a system to system certificate?

Comment: Well it’s pretty sketchy that they just gave you a certificate, that means they would have/know your private key. However, if they did provide you a complete certificate (public and private parts), the way to use it is to load the certificate (both public and private parts) into the system key store and then retrieve it in your code from there. Most basic examples for using certificates in C# show you how to do this.

Comment: @DaveM   I've made an update(above) and have tried your suggestion.

Comment: What does `Console.WriteLine(GetMyCert().HasPrivateKey);` print?

Comment: Return = FALSE ?

Comment: You need the private key for the certificate. If you don’t have it, there’s nothing you can do.